# Where is the direction of kinetic friction in this question?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, friction

> Suppose there is on object of 20.0kg sliding to the right. A person exert a force of 30N left on the object. The object has an acceleration of 2.5m/s^2 left. What is the magnitude and direction of kinetic friction?

Since the object is moving to the right (slowing down), I supposed the kinetic friction is to the left since it always opposes the direction of motion.

Take right to be positive.Thus, (-F) + (-30) = (20.0)(-2.5), -F = (-50) + (30), F = +(20N)

But isn't +20N mean the direction is right?

I'm a bit confused here.

Comment: You started with (-F) + (-30): ie you actually defined F as the force to the left!

Comment: I wonder if you can simplify. What is acceleration with friction? What is acceleration without friction? Subtract and F=ma?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your equation, you assumed (-F) is the frictional force, since it is acting towards right. Hence you got F = 20. Which effectively means -F = -20N

Or just assume frictional force is F irrespective of direction (assuming it is not known at this time). Then you will get F = -20N which means it acts towards right.